integral of nonelementary function with $\ln^2(x)$ and $\arctan^2(x)$
I am trying to calculate the following nonelementary integral,I hope to reach an analytical solution either exact or approximate.
$$ \iint\left(\frac{1}{4}\ln^2\left(\frac{r^2+l_g^2-2rl_g\sin{\theta}}{r^2+l_g^2+2rl_g\sin{\theta}}\right)+ \left(\arctan\left(\frac{2rl_g\cos{\theta}}{r^2-l_g^2}\right)+m\pi\right)^2\right)r\,drd\theta$$
It is a surface integral in a polar coordinate system
My first question is if it is even possible to get to an exact solution of this integral. And if not is there a way to get an approximate analytical result?
I already tried using taylor series for the natural logarithm and the arctangent, but they are only accurate about a single point, which doesn't work for me. I also looked into special functions, but i quickly got very confused there.
I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Is the argument of the logarithm correct? Right now it is $1$.

yeah i saw it to, changed up a minus for a plus

yes you are right. The domain ranges from -pi/2 to pi/2

@YvesDaoust The radius ranges from 0 to $l_g$ for $m=1$ and from $l_g$ to infinite for $m=0$
